# Cant see the picture in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I am working on [this website](http://www.wcride.com/) and as you can see there are three images in the middle. But when I open the website in IE8 or lower, the images are gone.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Are the images in CMYK? If yes than make it to RGB

Comment: Open your picture up in PhotoShop, discard profile if any, go to Image > Mode > RGB (instead of CMYK), File > Save As > Level 8 > OK

Comment: Images are already RGB..

Comment: @intekhabkhan tried any of the solutions given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like they said in the comments check if its `rgb`.

Make sure you dont have: < img src="your_source" `height="" width=""` alt="" /> This will make IE Think that it has 0 height and width.

Also try to relink the image's again.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the inline `width` style makes the images display correctly.

It seems to be clashing with `max-width:100%` from bootstrap.css (disabling that also works, although the inline `width` is easier to remove).

Probably the most practical solution would be to override the `max-width` from bootstrap by specifying `max-width` inline as well, alongside to the `width` and with the same value.